# ASP.NET Core MVCにてCurrent Context限定のGlobal変数を作りたい

Tags: model-view-controller, .net-core, asp.net-core

ASP.NET Core MVC（Core 3.1）のWebアプリケーションにおいて、
1 Request、1 Context内限定のGlobal変数を置きたいのですが、
どのような方法が適切でしょうか。

単純なSingletonを作り、処理完了後破棄するような実装の場合、
並列で動いたContext間で情報が共有されるため問題があります。

Comment: 何かこれあたりがそれらしいのでは？ [HttpContext.Items](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-3.1#httpcontextitems) `1 つの要求を処理している間データを格納するには、HttpContext.Items コレクションを使います。 要求が処理された後、コレクションの内容は破棄されます。`

Comment: バッチリなようです。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HttpContext.Items が実質的にCurrentContextのGlobal変数として働く。

AspNetCoreCurrentRequestContext と組み合わせることで、Applicationのどの場所からも参照することが可能になる。
https://qiita.com/taiga_takahari/items/d224b273a7ca66439429

```
AspNetCoreHttpContext.Current.Items["SomeKeyName"] = "SomeValue";
```